# Multiplicar duas colunas em um select

Tags: sql, oracle

Tenho duas colunas (`valor_unitario` e `quantidade`) queria fazer um select que multiplicasse todas as colunas do campo `valor_unitario * quantidade`.

Exemplo:

```
Valor_Unit|Quantidade
    15    *    2
          +
    10    *    1
```

Resultado: 40

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basicamente só é necessário realizar um `SUM` em cima da sua multiplicação das colunas:

```
SELECT SUM((Valor_Unit * Quantidade)) AS total
  FROM tabela
```

Comment: Obrigado era exatamente o que eu precisava

Comment: Sendo uma consulta recorrente pode ser criada uma coluna virtual na tabela.  https://www.oracletutorial.com/oracle-basics/oracle-virtual-column/